# Removing specific words within a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to clean lists within a column in my dataframe from all the terms that do not make sense.

For example

```
      Col                       New_Col                                 

        VM                       ['#']
        JS                       [ '/','/UTENTI/','//utilsit/promo', '/notifiche/']
  www.facebook.com               ['https://www.facebook.com/','https://twitter.com/']
        FA                       ['/nordest/venezia/','/nordest/treviso/']
```

I would like to remove from each list(row) in the column all the words that

- do not start with `https, http` or `//`
- contains Col as subset in `New_Col` (for example: `www.facebook.com` is included in `https://www.facebook.com/` so I should remove it, does not matter if it starts with `https`)

I tried to write this code:

```
prefixes=['http','https','//']

for word in df['New_Col']:
    if word.startswith(prefixes):
        list.remove(word)
print (df['New_Col'])
```

however it says that

> 'list' object has no attribute 'startswith'

(Attribute error). 
I think I am considering in my code above a list and not column with lists.

Can you please help me to understand how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use, [`DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) on `axis=1` along with custom filter function `fx`:

```
import re

fx = lambda s: [w for w in s['New_Col'] if s['Col'] not in w and re.match(r'^https?|//', w)]
df['New_Col'] = df.apply(fx, axis=1)
```

---

```
# print(df)
                Col                 New_Col
0                VM                      []
1                JS       [//utilsit/promo]
2  www.facebook.com  [https://twitter.com/]
3                FA                      []
```

Answer (score 0):

make a function to remove the words you want using regular expression and then apply it on the dataframe column as below:

```
df['ColName'].apply(lambda x: func(x))
```

Here **func** is the function that will take each row of the **ColName** column and will return your required result